# What free program has ability to crop a video and position itself within the boundaries I need over an an additional video and saving as one video?

Tags: windows, gratis, video

What free program has ability to

1. crop a Portion of video (e.g upper right), preferably by dragging a rectangle to the correct size & position
2. now take that piece and position it within the boundaries of a second video, so that it displays in front of the second video (picture in picture)
3. save the result as a new video

Comment: ffmpeg can probably do it - but I am not sure, because I can't understand your question. https://superuser.com is full with ffmpeg gurus.

Comment: The OP wants to overlay a video with another video (picture in picture). 1) crop video #1 to define a portion of it (e.g upper right) 2) have that video display in front of video #2 (hiding part of #2) 3) save the result as a single new video

Comment: DILTENDO.com I edited your question to make it clearer to others (it seemed clear enough to me). I hope that you don't mind. Please state an operating system (Windows/Linux/Mac/Android/IoS/other and say whether it must be free (add the [tag:gratis] tag, or state your budget. Best read [ask])  @RockPaperLizard can it be un-held now?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Yes. :)  Thank you for your edits and for the recommendations you made to the OP.

Comment: For a really quick and dirty version... get a screen capture software and just capture your own screen playing the two videos.